# Why does kube-proxy authenticate to the kube-api-server using service account instead of tls certificate

Tags: kubernetes

I am digging down into the Kubernetes PKI. I noticed that mostly all the control-plane components, including kubelet authenticate to the api-server using TLS certificates.

Only kube-proxy & flannel running as `Daemonsets` authenticate using a service account.
The documentation states:

> DaemonSet: Since the kubelet itself is loaded on each node, and is sufficient to start base services, you can run kube-proxy and other node-specific services not as a standalone process, but rather as a daemonset in the kube-system namespace. Since it will be in-cluster, you can give it a proper service account with appropriate permissions to perform its activities. This may be the simplest way to configure such services.

What is special here about `Daemonsets` regarding authentication? 
What is the point behind  "*Since the kubelet itself is loaded on each node and is sufficient to start base services*"?

Answer (score 4):

To better understand this question it is worth reminding the basic [Kubernetes components](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/).

[image: Kubernetes components]

Basically we can  divide cluster into:

- Master node: Control Plane, responsible for making global decisions about the cluster
- Worker Node(s) - responsible for running pods by providing the Kubernetes runtime environment.

Let's take a look at the "Node" (worker) section components:

> ##### kubelet
>
> An agent that runs on each  [node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/)  in the cluster. It makes sure that  [containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/)  are running in a  [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/).
> The kubelet takes a set of PodSpecs that are provided through various mechanisms and ensures that the containers described in those PodSpecs are running and healthy. The kubelet doesn't manage containers which were not created by Kubernetes.

> ##### kube-proxy
>
> kube-proxy is a network proxy that runs on each  [node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/)  in your cluster, implementing part of the Kubernetes  [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)  concept.
> [kube-proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/)  maintains network rules on nodes. These network rules allow network communication to your Pods from network sessions inside or outside of your cluster.
> kube-proxy uses the operating system packet filtering layer if there is one and it's available. Otherwise, kube-proxy forwards the traffic itself.

> ##### Container runtime
>
> The container runtime is the software that is responsible for running containers.
> Kubernetes supports several container runtimes:  [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/),  [containerd](https://containerd.io/docs/),  [CRI-O](https://cri-o.io/#what-is-cri-o), and any implementation of the  [Kubernetes CRI (Container Runtime Interface)](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-node/container-runtime-interface.md).

As the `kubelet` and Container runtime are two main components which are responsible for running pod and establishing connection to the Control Plane, they must be directly installed on the node's OS. It means also for `kubelet` it must have TLS certificates that you mentioned in your question for ensuring secure connection to the Control Plane. What about `kube-proxy`?

It could be installed in two ways during cluster provisioning - directly on the node's OS (for example, this way is used in the [Kubernetes The Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way)) or as the DaemonSet ([kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/)).

When `kube-proxy` is [installed directly](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/09-bootstrapping-kubernetes-workers.md#download-and-install-worker-binaries) it will have also separetly [generated TLS ceritficates](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/04-certificate-authority.md#the-kube-proxy-client-certificate), just like `kubelet`.

The second way, is the "DeamonSet" mentioned in your question. It means, instead of running as the OS deamon directly on the node, it will configured via [DeamonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) deployment and it will be running as the pod on every node. Advantages over running on the OS directly:

- Using DeamonSet features we are ensuring that in case of the failure, this pod will be automatically re-created on the node
- less interference directly with the node OS - instead of generating new pair TLS certificates, we will just use ServiceAccount

Answering your question:

> What is special here about Daemonsets regarding authentication?

To better understand it we can take a deeper look at the `kube-proxy` configured via DaemonSets using cluster provisioned with `kubeadm`. Based on [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/implementation-details/#proxy):

> A ServiceAccount for  `kube-proxy`  is created in the  `kube-system`  namespace; then kube-proxy is deployed as a DaemonSet:
>
> - The credentials (`ca.crt`  and  `token`) to the control plane come from the ServiceAccount
> - The location (URL) of the API server comes from a ConfigMap
> - The  `kube-proxy`  ServiceAccount is bound to the privileges in the  `system:node-proxier`  ClusterRole

There are three points. Let's first check the first one:

**The credentials - secret**

Get service account name from the pod definition:

```
kubectl get daemonset kube-proxy -n kube-system -o yaml
  ...
  serviceAccount: kube-proxy
  serviceAccountName: kube-proxy
  ...
```

As, can see, it has [assigned a Service Account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens) called `kube-proxy`:

Let's check it:

```
kubectl get sa kube-proxy -n kube-system -o yaml
```

Output:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-08-16T14:14:56Z"
  name: kube-proxy
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "259"
  uid: (UID)
secrets:
- name: kube-proxy-token-2qhph
```

As can see, we are referring to secret named `kube-proxy-token-2qhph`:

```
kubectl get secret kube-proxy-token-2qhph -n kube-system -o yaml
```

Output:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ca.crt: (APISERVER'S CA BASE64 ENCODED)
  namespace: (NAMESPACE BASE64 ENCODED)
  token: (BEARER TOKEN BASE64 ENCODED)
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: kube-proxy
    kubernetes.io/service-account.uid: ...
  creationTimestamp: "2021-08-16T14:14:56Z"
  name: kube-proxy-token-2qhph
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "256"
  uid: (UID)
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

[This secret contains](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens):

> The created secret holds the public CA of the API server and a signed JSON Web Token (JWT).

We are using this "JSON Web Token" bearer token for verifying requests:

> A service account is an automatically enabled authenticator that uses signed bearer tokens to verify requests.

> The signed JWT can be used as a bearer token to authenticate as the given service account. See [above](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#putting-a-bearer-token-in-a-request) for how the token is included in a request. Normally these secrets are mounted into pods for in-cluster access to the API server, but can be used from outside the cluster as well.

For getting more information about bootstrap tokens I'd recommend reading following Kubernetes docs: [Authenticating with Bootstrap Tokens](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/bootstrap-tokens/), [kubeadm token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-token/) and [Kubernetes RBAC 101: Authentication](https://www.cncf.io/blog/2020/07/31/kubernetes-rbac-101-authentication/).

**ConfigMap**

By following similar steps as for getting the ServiceAccount name, we will get ConfigMap name which is mounted to the `kube-proxy` pod:

```
kubectl get daemonset kube-proxy -n kube-system -o yaml
...
volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: kube-proxy
 ...
```

Now, let's get ConfigMap definition:

```
kubectl get cm kube-proxy -n kube-system -o yaml
```

```
  kubeconfig.conf: |-
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Config
    clusters:
    - cluster:
        certificate-authority: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        server: https://10.230.0.12:6443
      name: default
    contexts:
    - context:
        cluster: default
        namespace: default
        user: default
      name: default
    current-context: default
    users:
    - name: default
      user:
        tokenFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
```

This IP address in under `server:` is API address so `kube-proxy` knows it and can communicate with it.
There are also references to `ca.rt` and `token` that are mounted from `kube-proxy-token-2qhph` secret.

**ClusterRole**

Let's check earlier mentioned ClusterRole - `system:node-proxier`:

```
kubectl describe clusterrole system:node-proxier
Name:         system:node-proxier
Labels:       kubernetes.io/bootstrapping=rbac-defaults
Annotations:  rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: true
PolicyRule:
  Resources                        Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------                        -----------------  --------------  -----
  events                           []                 []              [create patch update]
  events.events.k8s.io             []                 []              [create patch update]
  nodes                            []                 []              [get list watch]
  endpoints                        []                 []              [list watch]
  services                         []                 []              [list watch]
  endpointslices.discovery.k8s.io  []                 []              [list watch]
```

We can that this role can list and watch endpoints of the node,enpoints, serivces etc...

By describing ClusterRoleBinding `kubeadm:node-proxier` we can confirm that role `system:node-proxier` is used by `kube-proxy` ServiceAccount:

```
kubectl describe clusterrolebinding kubeadm:node-proxier
Name:         kubeadm:node-proxier
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  system:node-proxier
Subjects:
  Kind            Name        Namespace
  ----            ----        ---------
  ServiceAccount  kube-proxy  kube-system
```

For getting more details I'd recommend reading [`kubeadm`  implementation details](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/implementation-details/).

Answering your second question:

> What is the point behind "*Since the kubelet itself is loaded on each node, and is sufficient to start base services*" ?

It just means that node established a connection with Control Plane (as `kubelet` is component responsible for that), so Control Plane can start scheduling `kube-proxy` pod on the node using predefined container runtime.